# Convert Octobercms to wintercms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I've been trying to migrate my octobercms site to wintercms. However i've failed to migrate. My Octobercms is from the time when it was opensource. That/s way back in 2021.

I've copied the composer.json file from wintercms and executed

```
composer install
```

composer starts updating everything but when it runs the scripts, it exits with an error.

```
 In Application.php line 1147:
             
 Unauthorized.
```

the same is true for any artisan commands. For e.g the following command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

gives the same error.

i've tried replacing artisan file but it still gives the same error.

Checked the logs. The following is the error.

```
    laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using 
     emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] 
    (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at 
    /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:210)
```

Any Ideas. Help/Pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Is this helpful? https://wintercms.com/blog/post/how-start-using-winter-cms

Comment: You're having several problems. Try to resolve them 1 by 1. First the logger. Configure your logger in config/logging (or whatever their location is. Take really close look at the .env file, it will help you. Then ` In Application.php line 1147: Unauthorized.`. Because you have a better logger it will give you better stack trace